# How to create more than one Actionbar like in Gmail App on Android

Tags: android, gmail, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

On Android Ice Cream Sandwich the GMail App has in the thread view, email headers with a action-bar-like layout. As you can see in the screenshots in portrait mode a header has only 2 icons and the remaining actions are hidden in an overflow menu. In landscape mode all actions are visible. The "real action bar" is at the top. How can you create additional bars like that?

[image: portraint mode]
[image: landscape mode]

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the application, not the system. This functionality is not provided by the SDK, but you could take the system action bar source code and use as a model/inspiration to integrate in your app. Ultimately, it's just a layout with some icons/buttons you click on. If you provide different layouts for portrait and landscape mode, you can achieve something similar.

Comment: The actionbar is more than just a layout. It has logic to show as many action icons as space is available, provides an overflow menu...

Comment: OK, it's a fairly smart layout. If you need the exact same functionality you might have to do more work. The question is, do you really?

Comment: I wonder if Google will go the Microsoft path. Providing better Apps through using own widgets/APIs which other parties have no access to. To be fair they should transfer improvements into the platform and not keep secret in own products. They cannot hide APIs because of Androids openness, but they have a knowledge advantage. Google is the platform vendor. But maybe they just didn't have time to transfer the custom action bar in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It has been long time, but if you are still looking for answer, I believe it is done via SplitActionBar.

To enable split action bar, simply add 
      `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`
to your 
`<activity>` or `<application>` manifest element.

you can find the information provided in Android Documentation
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: I was asking for the blue bar that is on top of every message. You are right, that the grey bar at the bottom can be added via  "splitActionBarWhenNarrow", but that's not the item I was asking for.